# PlayFramework jobs executed multiple times?

Tags: playframework

I have the following Job class (I've removed the actual job code):

```
@On("0 0 1 * * ?")
public class DailyJob extends Job
{
    @Override
    public void doJob() throws Exception
    {
// I log from here        
    }
}
```

My log tells me that this job is executed multiple times every day, while it should only be executed once per day (at 01:00). Today it was executed 4 times. The code is running on a tomcat instance on my customer's server. I've considered that the site might be running on multiple servers, but I've asked about this and they've said only one. So I would think 4 would be out of the question. However, I've made a lock in the function (on a static object), and inside the lock/synchronized I check and set the previous execution date (statc - System.currentTimeMillis()). And if it's less than 10 seconds ago, it should be logged. However, this doesn't happen, even if the job is executed 4 times within the same second. So I'm thinking it might be executed under 4 different environments.

I think it might run on play 1.2.2

Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but have you checked that the logs are not written 4 times?

Comment: :) I've set up this site on my local computer running in the same environment as the production server, and it's only logged once. I'm also getting hibernate locking/persistence exceptions, which indicate that more threads are dealing with the same stuff. (as far as I can understand) (Well, obviously it can't be 100% identical to the prod system, but more or less)

Comment: is it running as multiple instances on the same server? I have seen this tactic before to keep the size of the heap down for more efficient garbage collection

Comment: I'm not a Tomcat expert, but it seems like it's running on 5-6 different isolates or something (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I remember a similar bug fixed in a recent play version. Have you tried to use play 1.2.4 ?

Comment: Yes, using play 1.2.4 ... However, I wonder if it's a tomcat issue, launching the web app in multiple environments.